# Accessing the iPhone file system via Linux/Unix

Tags: software-rec, data-recovery, iphone

[My old iPhone is semi-bricked](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/questions/394/any-way-to-recover-data-from-a-semi-bricked-iphone). It turns off after a few minutes and doesn't get past the load screen.

It has important data on it which wasn't backed up. I'm trying to access the hard-drive's contents without resorting to a hard-drive recovery company.

Someone mentioned to me that you can [use a Linux machine and the program Amarok](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/iPhone) to access the drive's contents. However, my phone wasn't jailbroken nor had the usb tethering option enabled. Plus, it had a passcode on it, so I'm guessing this method wouldn't work.

Are there any other ways you can think of to access the drives contents using a Unix machine? Is there any way to take it apart and connect a cable directly to the hard-drive?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150211110123/http://everydaylht.com/howtos/desktop/iphoneipod-touch-on-linux/)* to see if it will give you what you need.

I haven't tried it yet, as I was looking at tethering which involves compiling some kernel drivers, but I don't think you'll need it for just accessing the contents.

Good luck!

* Apparently the original link does not work anymore (five years later). I've changed the link to a copy from archive.org.

Comment: The link does not work. It is redirecting one to a different ad site every time it is clicked.

Comment: The answer was written five years ago. Looks like that site is no longer around. I've changed the link in the answer to a copy from archive.org.